# Kinetic energy and momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum, collision

I was studying the conservation of momentum and energy and a question came to my mind. Both energy and linear and angular momentum are "numbers" that represent the symmetries in the interactions that our universe has (rotational, translational and temporal), so both momentum and energy are related to force. My question is, what makes kinetic energy the cause of feeling the forces in a collision and not linear momentum?

Comment: I try to explain my question better. Both energy and linear and angular momentum are "numbers" that represent the symmetries in the interactions that our universe has (rotational, translational and temporal), so both momentum and energy are related to force. My question is, what makes kinetic energy the cause of feeling the forces in a collision and not linear momentum?

Comment: In addition I have two contradictory examples collected from this forum, in one it says that a bull and a bullet have the same kinetic energy, but the bull has more momentum, and if they hit a target and come to rest the force exerted by the bull would be much greater than that of the bullet since F=dp/dt. In another example we have a rifle firing a bullet, both the rifle and the bullet have the same momentum, but the bullet has much more kinetic energy, and I think we all know what happens if you get hit by the bullet or the rifle.

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Eqs. (1) & (2) are not the definitions of momentum and kinetic energy.

Comment: @Qmechanic I know the question is badly phrased, so I have tried to rephrase it in the comments. How do you write equation like this?. I am new

Comment: @JL14 You don't have to do all the repair in the comments. You can edit your post by clicking the link that says "Edit" below the post.

Comment: In non-relativistic classical mechanics, kinetic energy is defined for a single particle as: $T = \frac{1}{2}m\left(\dot x^2+ \dot y^2 + \dot z^2\right)$, where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are particlels positions along cartesian coordinate axes, and $m$ is the particle's mass, and the dot notation means a derivative with respect to time (e.g., $\dot x = \frac{dx}{dt}$).

Comment: The work is not equal to the kinetic energy. The work done by the **net** force is equal to the **change** in kinetic energy.

Comment: Thanks to the person who told me that the questions could be edited, I have already edited it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141779/2451

Answer (score 0):

In a accident, there are way more variables than kinetic energy and momentum.

A bull and a bullet, if they have the same momentum, once they have come to a stop, they would have exerted the same forces if they stopped within the same time period.  But the bullet had more kinetic energy. so if they both were to hit a block of wood, the bullet would have done more damage because it had a higher kinetic energy which was converted into work done in the deformation of the block.

The bullet is deadly due to its small area of cross section which makes it able to pierce stuff rather easily.

If you took the kinetic energy vs momentum of a car in a car crash, The kinetic energy is the factor that converts to other forms of energy such as heat and deformation of the car and finally, if you were unfortunate enough, your deformation. The momentum of the car doesn't have much relevance in this area.

Your thought of kinetic energy vs momentum is very wrong as both of them are totally different.

Generally, we don't consider momentum as it is pretty irrelevant in everyday life and is studied only to make question solving easier when considering ideal scenarios with no external forces such as air drag, friction. etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the flaw in my logic. It is in the interpretation of Newton's second law. It says that F=dp/dt, but you have to take into account its physical sense, that is, that the momentum changes due to the action of a force and not the other way round. A change in momentum does not generate a force. So extrapolating this to an accident and being very reductionist, let's suppose that we only have a force against the car. This force will cause the linear momentum to change, but nothing else, it does not generate force, so it can have no effect on the damage we suffer. However, the same force that causes the momentum to change also does work, and this is where kinetic energy comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

Solid objects behave kind of like springs when they are compressed/stretched (strained), meaning the atoms in the material react to the strain by creating a force proportional to the strain to try to return to the original shape. At a certain amount of strain the material will break, and for that to happen the applied force due to the collision must have overcome the restoring force of the material and compressed it to that point, i.e. the impact must do enough *work* to break the material (measured as the 'toughness' of the material). Therefore the incoming object must have enough kinetic energy to do this work and cause the damage, and the more kinetic energy an object has the more damage it can do.

That being said, the collision must also produce enough force to overcome the maximum value of the materials restoring force, and the force produced by a collision depends on both energy and momentum so really both properties are important.

Answer (score 0):

In the mechanical realm, objects deform or break because we apply work to them. That is to say, we deform them over some distance with an applied external force. Higher kinetic energies have the potential to generate higher forces and/or cause higher deformations. How long we take to apply the force over time is not relevant. That is to say, $\int\ F\ dt$ is irrelevant in defining what amount of damage is caused.

In summary, two objects with the same kinetic energy but different masses--a high speed pellet or a slow moving locomotive train--can do comparable damage at impact because the same amount of kinetic energy is converted to work. Comparing the two objects shows that the same damage is done even though the two objects have different momentum values--the lighter object has lower momentum.