# Non-uniqueness of solutions in Newtonian mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, variational-principle

In [*The Variational Principles of Mechanics*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1258635) by Lanczos, in section 1 of Chapter 1, Lanczos states that for a complicated situation, the Newtonian approach fails to give a unique answer to the problem, in contrast to the analytical mechanics approach.

Can anyone provide an example where the Newtonian approach cannot give a unique solution to a mechanics problem?  I don't mean a trivial response like simply re-expressing a solution in a different inertial frame, but a "complicated" situation that Lanczos had in mind.  I cannot think of any.

Comment: For non-determinism in Newtonian mechanics, see e.g. [Norton's dome](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39632/2451)

Comment: There are a variety of hard-contact problems in Newtonian mechanics which fail to give unique solutions. For example, the simultaneous collision of three spheres. Of course such problems are obviously a mathematical curiosity since they involve infinitely sharp contact potentials, but they are fun to think about. There are also some strange solutions that occur with certain initial conditions (such as a swinging pendulum given just enough energy to reach its apex), also of course unrealistic since the initial conditions have to be perfectly fine tuned.

Comment: Thanks, Nanite.  I think this is along the lines of what Lanczos was getting at.  Would you happen to know of any treatment of this problem (3 spheres scattering elastically)?  I googled it and didn't find anything, and I've tried to work it myself and the math is getting pretty ugly.

Comment: Another example is a ball colliding with two walls at once (i.e. an inside corner), where the angle $\theta$ between the walls is something other than $90^\circ$. Mathematically, two reflections in planes make a rotation by twice the angle between the planes, but the direction of rotation depends on the order of the two reflections. So the ball's velocity can turn by $2\theta$ either left or right.

Comment: But that's assuming that there are actually two collisions happening in succession. If it's considered as a single collision, then the direction of the force on the ball is not determined; it could be anywhere between the two walls' normal vectors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what Lanczos had in mind, but Norton's dome is an example of nonuniqueness. There is a large literature on this system and its philosophical implications (or lack thereof).

- Norton, "Causation as Folk Science," http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1214/
- Korolev, "Indeterminism, asymptotic reasoning, and time irreversibility in classical physics," 2006, http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/3003/
- Jon Pérez Laraudogoitia, "On Norton’s dome," Synthese, 2012, http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs11229-012-0105-z
- Fletcher, What Counts as a Newtonian System? The View from Norton’s Dome
- David Malament, Norton's Slippery Slope, Philosophy of Science 75 (5):799-816 (2008)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to these references, Norton's dome is a new concept for me to think about.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say fluid mechanics problems. You might want to check Navier-Stokes equations which are basically derived from a newtonian perspective.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Under what circumstances are the solutions non-unique?

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear on my answer. It is still an open question whether the solutions of three dimensional incompressible N-S equations are unique or not. http://www.claymath.org/millennium/Navier-Stokes_Equations/