# Can phase trajectories intersect for non-autonomous system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, chaos-theory

There has been enough discussion about intersection of phase trajectories in autonomous system,where the system wasn't time dependent. And we came to the conclusion that, at a point in space there can't be two futures and two stories of history over the course of evolution, hence phase trajectories can't intersect. But I haven't found any conclusive discussion of the same about non autonomous system(time dependent). Though in some research work, I found the following statement:

> *"non-autonomous system trajectories can have self intersection and two different trajectories can intersect in later time."*

Please explain the reason for the same. I've attached a screenshot from that paper.
[image]

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/578836/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the research paper rightly points that for non-autonomous system trajectories may intersect. The gist of this concept lies in the definition of autonomous and non-autonomous system.
For a non-autonomous system:

[image: Non-autonomous system]

And for an autonomous system:
[image]

Thus for a non-autonomous system, the equation governing the evolution of system changes with time due to the variable '$t$' in the equations. However, this doesn't happen for an autonomous system. Thus an argument similar to your explanation can be raised i.e.:

> *"As the rules governing the evolution of system with time, change with time so we still have a unique past and future even if these trajectories intersect."*

Comment: Hi Aditya, and welcome to the Physics SE! The equations become much easier to read, search and edit when [mathjax](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5610/75633) is used. It'd be great if you could use it in your next posts.

Comment: @stafusa Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Yes, trajectories of non-autonomous systems can cross in phase space.

One way to understand why is to consider that the system's explicit time dependence means that the time $t$ is needed to unambiguously determine the state of the system, i.e., the "complete" phase space includes an extra dimension $t$ besides, say, $(x,y)$: so what appears as a crossing in space $x \times y$ only seems so because it's a *projection* (over $x \times y$) of the (non-self-crossing) trajectory in the 3-D space $x \times y \times t$.

[image: Curve apparent crossing]