# Is it possible to built a variational principle for this first-order system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, differential-equations

Imagine there is a mechanical system described in unitary units by the [equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%27%3D-sgn%28x%29*sqrt%28%7Cx%7C%29%2C+x%280%29%3D1):
$$\dot{x} = -\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{|x|},\quad x(0)=1 \tag{Eq. 1}$$
such it has a finite duration [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F4*%281-t%2F2%2B%7C1-t%2F2%7C%29%5E2):
$$x(t) = \frac{1}{4}\left(1-\frac{t}{2}+\left|1-\frac{t}{2}\right|\right)^2 \tag{Eq. 2}$$

**Is this enough information to reconstruct its Kinetic and Potential Energies to obtain its Lagrangian of this System and its Least Action Principle's integral? What are these values in terms of $x(t)$?**

**Motivation**

Recently I have learned about the existence of finite duration solutions of differential equations on these papers: [Finite Time Differential Equations](https://doi.org/10.1109/CDC.1985.268832) and [Finite Time Controllers](https://doi.org/10.1137/0324047) by Vardia T. Haimo, and since everyday phenomena are of finite duration, I want to know how will behave the Energy and the Least Action Principle on this kind of system with finite duration solutions, and this is the only example I have so far of an autonomous system that stands finite duration solutions (maybe $\dot{y} = -\sqrt{y},\,y(0)=1$ also works if the solutions is restrained to the reals, since after $(y,\,\dot{y})=(0,\,0)$ the derivative is never going to rise up again since the square root is positive).

**I am trying to make a mechanical system with $x(t)$ the solution to their equation of motions, not in the other way.**

Comment: Mechanical system is described by second order differential equation

Comment: @Eli I left the explicit solution $x(t)$: It is not possible to obtain the equations of motion by differentiated it twice?

Comment: the equations of motion are described by the Newton second law.

Answer (score 2):

1. A 1st-order [ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation) $$\dot{x}~=~f(x,t)\tag{A}$$ cannot be a [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) if we are only allowed to use a single real variable $x(t)$, cf. e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4394187/11127) Math.SE post.
2. With several variables it is easy. We can e.g. use a Lagrange multiplier
   $$ S[x,\lambda]~=~ \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\!dt~ \lambda(\dot{x}-f(x,t)) \tag{B}$$
3. Care should be taken wrt. boundary conditions, so that they are compatible with the physical system at hand, i.e. one might need to add boundary terms to the action (B).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Since the explicit solution is given, I was expecting to form the kinetic energy as $K=\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}$ ($m=1$, and $\dot{x}$ from the equation), use a generic potential $V$ and since the $\int\,K - V\,dt$ should give the same equation for $\dot{x}$ one could determine $V$ (again, this because I know the explicit solution of $x(t)$). If this approach is mistaken, It could be possible to obtain the equation of motion from the Work-Energy Theorem? (since I have the initial Kinetic energy, and the final Kinetic Energy is zero - the solution $x(t)$ is of finite-duration)

Comment: Hi Joako, For starters, your proposed kinetic term $K=\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}$ is a total time derivative, and hence does not contribute to the EL equation.

Comment: Let me see If I am following you: From mechanics principles (like Newton´s laws, Lagrangian/Hamiltonian, others) it is possible to obtain the equations of motion, but from the equation of motion, is not always possible to reconstruct these principle's equations back?

Comment: Forget variational principles for a moment. How did you/Can you derive eq. (1) from Newton's laws?

Comment: Don´t really know... I am trying to form a mechanical system that can stand a solution of finite duration from the only example with explicit solution I know, so I am working backwards.... an alternative idea could be differentiating one time the equation $\dot{y} = -\sqrt{y}$ which also stand the same solution (since is also non Lipschitz at zero)... the second derivative will be the $F\cdot a$ term and the other side a potential, something similar to the Norton's Dome but with convergent instead of divergent solutions.

Comment: As example, I see you edit this [question about the Norton's Dome](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39632/317057), where if I take the equation $\ddot{r} = \sqrt{r},\,r(0)=9,\,r'(0)=-6$ I know now I can have the solution $r(t)=\frac{1}{144}(6-t)^4 \theta(6-t)$ with $\theta(t)$ the Heaviside unitary step function, because of why I am using on the second "added later" [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4408192/909869)

Comment: Actually, it stand the family of finite-duration solutions $r(t) = \frac{1}{144}(T-t)^4\theta(T-t)$ for and ending time $T$ defined by the initial condition $r(0) = \frac{T^4}{144}$ and $r'(0) = -\frac{T^3}{36}$... is kind of different from the Norton's Dome where the time T is kind of arbitrary and made all the mess, for a finite duration solutions the initial condition already fix the solution since always have the border condition $r(T)=r'(T) = 0$.