# Is Norton's dome valid (or does $\frac{d^2 \vec{p}}{dt^2} = \vec{0} \implies \frac{d^n \vec{p}}{dt^n} = \vec{0} \ \forall \ n > 2$)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, symmetry-breaking, determinism

I came across [Norton's dome](https://sites.pitt.edu/%7Ejdnorton/Goodies/Dome/index.html) and I don't agree that it proves anything.

First, here's an obviously ridiculous and completely nonsensical example that I constructed from thinking about simple harmonic motion:

Consider a particle of unit mass at rest in free space, at $x = 0$. Newton's second law states that $\ddot{x} = 0$ at $t=0$. There's an obvious way to describe the particle's motion that satisfies Newton's second law of motion, and that is $x(t) = 0$. Let us denote this solution by $s_1(t)$.

However, here's another non-obvious way to describe the particle's motion that satisfies Newton's second law:
$$
x(t) = \begin{cases}
\sin(t - T) - t + T \quad &\text{if  }\ t \ge T \\
0 & \text{if }\ t < T
\end{cases}
$$
Let us denote this solution by $s_2(t)$.

Notice that $s_2(t)$, $\dot{s_2}(t)$ and $\ddot{s_2}(t)$ all obviously equal $0$ for all $t < T$.

Now consider time $t = T$. Notice that:
$$
\begin{align*}
s_2(T) & = \sin(T - T) - T + T = 0 \\
\dot{s_2}(T) & = \cos(T - T) - 1 = 0 \\
\ddot{s_2}(T) & = -\sin(T - T) = 0
\end{align*}
$$

Thus, $s_2(t)$ is a completely valid solution which obeys the constraint that the particle is at rest at time $t=0$. However, notice that as $t$ grows beyond $T$, [the particle starts to spontaneously shoot off to infinity in the negative $x$ direction](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/flvpowwvbs). Also notice that $T$ is an arbitrarily chosen constant, it could assume any positive real number as its value.

Thus, the second solution states that the particle could spontaneously start shooting off to infinity in the negative $x$ direction after some arbitrary amount of time $T$.

So we have proven that Newtonian mechanics isn't deterministic, can harbor uncaused events, yada yada.

#### Why are Norton's dome and my example not valid?

They're incorrect because in those solutions, the particle isn't really at rest when the spontaneous motion starts occurring. Notice that the fourth derivative of $r(t) = \frac{d^4}{dt^4} \left( \frac{(t - T)^4}{144} \right) = \frac{1}{6}$, and that the third derivative of $s_2(t)$ at $t=T$ is equal to $-\cos(T-T) = -1$.

Clearly Norton believes that an object being "at rest" does not necessitate that $\frac{d^n \vec{p}}{dt^n} = \vec{0} \ \forall \ n \ge 2 $.  He believes that Newton's first law does not imply $ \frac{d^2 \vec{p}}{dt^2} \implies \frac{d^n \vec{p}}{dt^n} = \vec{0} \ \forall \ n \ge 2 $.

However, believing this leads to all sorts of completely nonsensical predictions for even the simplest system one can think of, a particle at rest in free space, as I have shown above.

Therefore, it only makes sense to believe that $ \frac{d^2 \vec{p}}{dt^2} = \vec{0} \implies \frac{d^n \vec{p}}{dt^n} = \vec{0} \ \forall \ n > 2$.

So, coming to my questions: Are my arguments valid? Is Norton's second solution just plain incorrect? If you disagree with my arguments and instead agree with Norton, what do you think of my completely nonsensical second solution for a particle at rest in free space?

Comment: Maybe I've missed something, but it seems like the big difference is that Norton's dome satisfies the equation of motion $\ddot{r} = \sqrt{r}$ at all times, while your equation only satisfies your equation of motion $\ddot{x} = 0$ for $t < T$.  Or, to put it another way, Norton's dome is [autonomous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)) and your example isn't.

Comment: In other words:  the weirdness of Norton's dome is that we can find multiple solutions with the same initial conditions that satisfy a given ODE for all time.  You've provided an example where the two solutions $s_1$ and $s_2$ satisfy the same ODE for $t < T$ and different ODEs for $t \geq T$, which is hardly surprising.

Comment: I don't really understand your point. You could set $T=0$ and then you'd have $\ddot{x} = -x$ at all times. That's a nonsensical solution too, isn't it? Anyway, I don't see what satisfying a single ODE has to do with this. Couldn't I come up with an equally nonsensical example that satisfies a single ODE for all $t$?

Comment: If you can come up with an equally nonsensical example that satisfies a single ODE for all $t$, then I think your question would be improved by including it in favor of the one you currently have.

Comment: (Also, even if you set $T = 0$, the solution $s_2$ has $\ddot{s}_2 = -\sin t \neq -s_2 = -\sin t + t$.)

Comment: I apologize, I forgot about the $-(t - T)$ term I had added to ensure that $\dot{s_2}(T) = 0$. $x(t) = \sin(t)$ satisfies $\ddot{x} = -x \ \forall \  t$.

Comment: Related: [Norton's dome and its equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39632/2451)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your example is *not* analogous to Norton's dome.

Norton's point is that Newtonian mechanics says that the trajectory of a particle obeys $\ddot{x}(t) = F(x(t),\dot{x}(t), t)$ *at every point in time $t$*, and that physics hence is often interpreted to constitute a notion of "causation" between the force $F$ and the motion $x(t)$ as the solution $x(t)$ is usually claimed to be unique (as a consequence of various uniqueness theorems about solutions to differential equations, it often is) given an initial position $x(t_0)$ and velocity $\dot{x}(t_0)$.

What you're talking about has nothing to do with either Norton's dome - or, indeed, Newtonian mechanics - since your $s_2(t)$ only obeys the differential equation $\ddot{s}_2(t) = 0$ at $t \leq T$, and not for all times $t$. $s_2(t)$ is hence *not* a valid solution to the equations of motion.

In contrast to this, Norton's dome purposefully constructs a dome with a shape such that its associated $F$ acting on a particle sliding over it is not Lipschitz continuous, and hence the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) can no longer guarantee uniqueness of the solution to the equatios of motion. Then, Norton shows explicitly that there are two *different* solutions $x(t)$ that *both* start with the particle at rest at the top of the dome (in the simple, colloquial sense $\dot{x} = 0$ - the particle isn't moving) and *both* solve the equations of motion for all times $t$.

Sure, you could force uniqueness in this case by says that you need to specify *all* derivatives of $x(t)$ at $t_0$, but that's not what physics does - a *lot* of classical physics is founded on the idea that position and velocity at a given time (or position and momentum) completely specify the state of a particle since they suffice to produce a unique trajectory via the equations of motion (there could be a digression about gauge theory here but that would be beside the point).

Also, note that e.g. for analytic functions, knowing all derivatives means knowing the value of the function at every point - this would mean the equations of motion lose their predictive power if we essentially need to know the solution already to fully specify it, and the idea of "causation" that Norton is concerned about would no longer enter.

Comment: I have no idea what Lipschitz continuous means but in Norton's second solution $\ddot{r}(t) > 0 \ \forall \ t > T$. Your answer makes no sense. By your own logic, Norton's second solution is not valid.

Comment: @royaljelly Norton isn't talking about a free particle, so his solution obeys $\ddot{r}(t) = F(r,\dot{r},t)$ for the non-zero $F$ of Norton's dome, not $\ddot{r}(t) = 0$. The definition of Lipschitz continuity is easily reached (with a single click!) from the P-L theorem page I linked.

Comment: I've looked at the relevant Wikipedia pages and I sort of understand your argument but I can't accept that a mass could spontaneously start rolling off a dome. I'm inclined to say that Norton's second solution is invalid precisely because it allows for nondeterministic behavior. Also, I was under the impression that solutions $x(t)$ are claimed to be unique because that's how physical systems work in real life.

Comment: @royaljelly *"but I can't accept that a mass could spontaneously start rolling off a dome."* Norton isn't making a point about what may or may not happen *in reality*. He's making a point about the *mathematical formalism of Newtonian mechanics* and how it does *not* exhibit the notion of unique "causation" that many people usually attribute to it. His argument is, mathematically, entirely correct (and that's what your question was about). That the *philosophical* implications of this are either unclear or uncomfortable is precisely the point of his example and why it is so widely discussed.