# Does Newton's 2nd Axiom follow directly from the 1st?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, inertial-frames

Newton's first axiom states that a body on which no forces act moves in a straight line with constant speed (magnitude of velocity vector), the second axiom states that $\vec{F_{tot}}=\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}$. My question is, is the first axiom superflous? Does it follow directly from the first?

The case relevant to this question is $\vec{F}=\vec{0}$. Only with the second law one can derive that bodies with no fores acting on them move in straight lines.

$F=\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}=\frac{dm}{dt}\vec{v}+m\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}=\vec{0} \rightarrow \frac{dm}{dt}\vec{v}=-m\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$

This can only be true if $\vec{v} \space$and $\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} \space$ are parallel, meaning acceleration only happens parallel to the direction of v, so the particle only moves in a line. The fact that $\vec{v} \parallel \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}$ leads to motion on a line can be shown more rigorously as well. The linear part of the first axiom is contained within the second axiom.

What about the constant speed $\frac{d||\vec{v}||}{dt}=0 \space$ part?

$\vec{v}=||v||\hat{v}, \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}=||\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}||\hat{(\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt})}$

$\vec{v} \parallel \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} \rightarrow \hat{(\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt})}=\pm\hat{v}, \frac{dm}{dt}||v||\hat{v}=-m||\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}||\hat{(\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt})}$

$\frac{dm}{dt}||v||=\mp m||\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}||$

I am able to get this far, but am unsure if this implies  $\frac{d||\vec{v}||}{dt}=0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Newton's first law necessary?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122231/)

Comment: If the OP is worried about the last sentence, he won't find an answer in the "duplicated question". If so, I'm voting to reopen

Comment: In the formulation of 2nd law $\mathbf F=d\mathbf p/dt$, $m$ is assumed constant. If we want to describe body whose mass changes in time, this formulation is not appropriate. The appropriate formulation is  $\mathbf F = m\mathbf a$ , where $\mathbf F$ includes contribution due to leaving/incoming mass.

Comment: @BioPhysicist in the last answer on that post, the linked paper on non-uniqueness of solutions of Newton's equations without the first axiom is explored for very specific cases where probelms arise for example from lack of higher derivatives at certain points. I am interested in if there are differences in much simpler cases, along the lines of such cases as I am exploring at the end of the post. If one can derive the $\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}=\vec{0} \space$ identity from only the second axiom also interests me specifically.