# What does Newton's first law of motion want to say?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames

[Newton's first law of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion) says

> "A body will remain in a state of rest or in uniform motion in straight line, unless acted by an external force."

So if a body is accelerated or moved uniformly in a circle, the state also changes its state by an external force.

Why does Sir Issac Newton use the state of rest or uniform motion in a straight line?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of research-efforts.

Comment: What you mean ? This is a valid question

Comment: Don't you answer your question the line before asking it?

Comment: The first law of Newton (discovered by Galileo Galilei) wants to say that a body can move (with constant speed and in a straight line) even if no force acts on it. Aristotel believed that a body can move only if pushed or pulled by a force.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13557/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Newton's 1st Law is making a statement about the very nature of straight-line constant speed motion: no outside force needed. That includes zero speed, too. Do you think it means something else?

Comment: When there's no external force on a body it could be at rest and stay at rest. It could be moving in a straight line at a uniform speed and keep moving in a straight line at a uniform speed. And then after the law he starts to go into other examples, such as a uniform spinning body spinning uniformly subject to no external forces (and not weird internal forces) and it continues to spin uniformly. You could even have other cases too, but to try to make other cases your object starts to be non uniform and so you really have subparts and then you'd want to use all three laws on the subparts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newton's first law is *not* about forces changing the way things move. That's the content of the second law.

The first law states what happens when *no force* acts. It *defines* an object on which no net forces act as an object which travels in a straight line or is at rest.

Comment: Sir uniform circular motion also contain no net force.                Why Sir Issac Newton use the statof rest or uniform in straight line ??

Comment: @SyedUzairAliShah: It does. Centripetal force is required to sustain circular motion.

Comment: @SyedUzairAliShah: Hint: for circular motion $a=v^2/r\neq0$

Comment: @SyedUzairAliShah: (you can include the @ symbol to respond to a particular user) I suppose you could say that $r=\infty$ for linear motion so that $a=v^2/\infty\approx0$. Outside of that, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: ACuriousMind centripetal forc cancel by centrifuge fore.           Uniform circular motion haven't any net force.                    Why sir Issac Newton use the state of rest or uniform motion in straight line

Comment: @SyedUzairAliShah: That's just not true, they don't "cancel". Fictitious forces [don't cancel anything](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/93637/50583). Also, you don't need to repeat your question at the end of every comment.

Comment: Kyle Kanos I want to ask, to stop or move any thing we need a force ..     It's doesn't matter the object in rest ,accalarate ,uniform in straight line and unform  circular motion                                but in first law of motion Sir Newton say's " if a object remain at rest or moves uinformaly in straight line it always remain at there position unless acted by an external force".         Why here use only two states

Comment: "centripetal force cancel by centrifuge force". This is a common misunderstanding. Many people believe that if $F=ma$ is true then the two forces acting on the body, F and ma (which is measured in N but is not a force in reality), cancel each other and no net force pushes or pulls the body.

Comment: @SyedUzairAliShah because the universe just happened to be like this, if he included circular motion his laws would not work.

Comment: Energizer777 you mean to say uniform circular motion have completely net force less ??

Comment: bruce smitherson if he including circular motion why her law would not work??

Comment: I told you, because our universe is not that way. It might be valid in a different universe with other laws. Physicists are just trying to figure it out how this particular universe works

Comment: ACuriousMind your concept help me thank you very much                   .

Answer (score 2):

That "*unless*" in Newton's law is key. Maybe a more useful way of understanding Newton's statement is as follows:

> **If** we see an object that has changed from being at rest to moving (or the other way around), or from moving in a *given straight line*
>   to *another, different straight line* (think here of the tangents to a
>   circle at two different points), **then** we'll say that an *external
>   force* has acted on it.
>
> And viceversa: **if** an external force acts on an object, **then** its effect
>   will be to change its state in one of the ways stated above, i.e., from
>   moving to rest (or viceversa) or from one straight line to another.

I deliberately simplified things here. This however captures the essence. For instance, in a circular movement, there is a constant force acting on the object and this forces is thus *constantly* (and continuously) changing the tangent (its velocity) along which the objects moves at any given instant.

However, the precise way to think of Newton's first law is that

- There is a force $\mathbf{\vec{F}}$ acting on a body whenever $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{\vec{V}}\neq0$.
- and viceversa, if there is a force $\mathbf{\vec{F}}$ acting on a body, then it will be $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{\vec{V}}\neq 0$

That is as much as Newton's laws go into actually *defining what a force **is***. Strictly speaking they only tell us **how to identify that a force is acting on a body**. Or, to put it in yet another words, **when we shall talk about *force***.

EDIT: 
Note: After reading the last comments I get your problem is in understanding how it can be enough to just "talk" about straight lines or at rest in this law. Isn't Newton missing other states? doesn't he need more generality? The answer is no. In order to convince yourself, try thinking about any kind of movement as a succession of straight-line moves, but very, very short, actually, infinitesimally short. Mathematics can help us in making sense of this. It involves a differential equation for the rate of change of the velocity of an object.

Comment: Minor quibble on notation: \mathbf makes \vec superfluous (and vice versa)

Comment: Sir I want to ask if you say that Sir Newton not missing any state but he state only two why ??       Where the other states ??

Comment: @KyleKanos That's right. Have used both here just to highlight it more for the OP.

Comment: @SyedUzairAliShah He doesn't need to discuss all possible states. He realized that we can understand any movement as a succession of straight-line movements. That's what I pointed to in my very last paragraph.

Comment: @SyedUzairAliShah Consider the dodecagon of this picture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecagon It follows quite closely the circle. You can imagine that, if instead of 12 sides we would use a poligon with say 100 sides, the approximation to a circle would be way better. It is in this sense that Newton saw he didn't need to worry about more complicated states of movement.

Answer (score 0):

Moved **uniformly** in a circle is not correct.Circular motion is always accelerated due to change of direction.Straight line is here important as Newton's first law talks about two cases-what happens to a body in rest/motion when force acts on it or when it does not.To keep a body moving in a circle a constant external force is needed to change it's direction at every point.(You can imagine a circle as a polygon with infinite number of small points.)